# Problemas em implementar o recurso do jQueryUI Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

E fiz uma pesquisa rápida sobre esse recurso e encontrei essa pagina;

https://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Então criei uma pasta com o nome de GUJ e dentro desta pasta coloquei três arquivos;

Um de JavaScript com o nome de jquery-2.2.2.min.js e o outro com o nome de jquery-ui.js

E coloquei também o arquivo index.html

com essas configurações;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.js"></script>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#accordion").accordion({
      collapsible: true
    });

</script>


</head>
<body>
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>First header</h3>
  <div>First content panel</div>
  <h3>Second header</h3>
  <div>Second content panel</div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Era para ter esse resultado;

https://jsfiddle.net/a2w4zs3h/

Mas não aconteceu nada.

aceito sugestões.

Comment: Os caminhos do script estão devidamente corretos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lembre-se que em jQuery o script deve ser usado dentro da função do `ready`

Faça como abaixo e tudo ocorrerá bem:

```
          $(document).ready(function(e){ // essa é a parte que você esqueceu
            $("#accordion").accordion({
              collapsible: true
            });        
          });
```

Se a resposta servir, dê um UP.

Comment: muito obrigado, deu certo.